# SQL Query - Previous 12 months Sum - Dynamically

Tags: sql, dynamic, ssms, cumulative-sum

I have a below table with me in which I have 2 years sales data with me and with multiple heads. I want to do running total of previous 12 months for all the heads. So for example if I am in Apr - 2019, my running total should give me sum of sales from May-2018 to Apr-2019 (12 months). And it should change dynamically as my month gets changed. The output should look something like below.

[image]

It would be very helpful for me if anyone can guide me on this. Please feel free to ask any questions regarding the requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't tried any thing, have a look at the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause for [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yes. I tried Over partition but wasn't using ROWS BETWEEN. Tried few things from that. It is working fine now. Thanks a lot :)